# Are there paper about black box testing of optic flow algorithms?

Tags: computer-vision, reference-request, optical-flow

Do papers exist about comparisons of the resulting optic flow and its precision compared to the used optic flow method?

I would like to find paper that dealt with this topic in some way and had discussed different ways to conquer this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Middlebury, which evaluates almost all the algorithms and their evaluation results are online:

http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/eval/results/results-n1.php

Or simply click any of the links at: http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/eval/

They also have a paper on their research and evaluation methodology.